# Form tree structure from qstandarditemmodel data

Tags: qt, treeview

I have a csv file which has data as follows:

```
type1, item1, <parameters of item1>
type2, item2, <parameters of item2>
type3, item3, <parameters of item3>
type4, item4, <parameters of item4>
type4, item5, <parameters of item5>
type5, item6, <parameters of item6>
type5, item7, <parameters of item7>
type1, item8, <parameters of item8>
type2, item9, <parameters of item9>
...
```

In the above data, the items 2 to 7 belong to type 1 (i.e, item1 is the parent of elements item2 to item7 and they might or might not be of the same type).

My goal is to display the above data in the form of a tree structure. For this, I have first fetched all the data from the csv file into a QStandardItemModel.
Now I am unsure of how to proceed from hereon in order to display the above in the form of a tree.

Could someone help me with advice on how to proceed from here.

Comment: How do you determine that item2 or item7 has parent item1? From 
scheme of csv file it is not clear.

Comment: item 2 or item 7 belong to the group type 1. After several lines again type1 is repeated. Lets say item 1 is a node in a network and all the items under this item1 are the links going out and coming from several other nodes. Which is why I said that item1 is the parent to item 2 and item7.

Comment: Is the csv file from you? I yes, it will be better if you use a XML file, Qt can natively handle this.

Comment: Do you mean try to form an xml file from this data and use the xml file @Boiethios

Comment: If there is some "static" data (I mean that will not be changed from outside), it will be better to write it as a XML format (that is very good at representing some tree architecture) and use it to build the tree widget. Parsing a CSV file and build the tree will make you lose some time otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `QStandardItemModel` doesn't match a tree for the simple reason there is no QmodelIndex parent. In your case the column in your csv file represent the level of an item, while the row is the path.

You need to implement the "tree-like" nature of your data into a model. You have 3 choices :

1. `QAbstractProxyModel` on top of your `QStandardItemModel`, use the default `QTreeView`. This is the generic way of doing things (could be use with any table model). It allow you to understand model indexes without messing with the work you would have done this far.
2. subclass `QabstractItemModel` and ditch your current QStandardItemModel, use the default `QTreeView`. This is how I would have done from the beginning.
3. create your own `QAbstractItemView` subclass to use with a QStandardItemModel. This is the most MVC way, but because Qt views actually have to deal with the rendering details, this is not recommended.

Go with option 1. and use the qt example [simple tree model](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) for inspiration. Please also see [my answer on a very similar problematic](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html) to understand how you need to subclass models

Edit : There is a **QGroupingProxyModel** in an ***unofficial*** library [QAdvancedItemViews](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qadvanceditemviews) which claim to do exactly what I propose in my first option.